# Show fragment from Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have application which uses several fragments for showing different tabs. 
The first fragment is List View with custom cell. Each cell has its own set of buttons. I want to show different fragment when a button is clicked. To know when the desired button is clicked I added an onclick event in the array adapter for my list. Is there a way to show the new fragment from Array Adapter. What I tried so far and it didn`t worked :

```
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)mContext)getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =                  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    PostFragment postFr = new PostFragment();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, postFr);


    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: You're missing a period before `getSupportFragmentManager` and the base Activity class doesn't have that method

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
PostFragment postFr = new PostFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, postFr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`getSupportFragmentManager`() is only defined for the class `FragmentActivity`, not for `Activity`

Comment: I see it now. It'd be useful if you could explain that in your answer

Comment: This could throw a ClassCastException if he passed getApplicationContext() into the constructor of his adapter (where he is calling this code from), rather than passing getActivity()

Comment: @Petar Ivanov did u try it?

Comment: No i didn`t. Tried the other solution. Will try this one later.

Answer (score 0):

what specifically went wrong when you tried to do that?

This is the method I use to go to a new fragment. I put it in an abstract BaseActivity class (extends AppCompatActivity) so that all of my implementing activities have use of the method.

The method takes the fragment you want to go to, and a boolean variable to indicate whether or not to add the transaction to the backstack.

The activity must have a FrameLayout declared in its XML resource file, with an id of "container". This is where the fragments will be placed.

```
public void gotoFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

In order to call this method from your ArrayAdapter class, pass an instance of the BaseActivity into the constructor of your Adapter.

For the Context parameter of the adapter, pass getActivity() from the fragment.

If all of your activity classes extend the BaseActivity class, you can safely say in your adapter:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private BaseActivity mActivity;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context pContext, int pLayoutResource, List<Object> pItems) {
    super(pContext, pLayoutResource);
    mActivity = (BaseActivity) pContext;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    if (mActivity != null) {
        mActivity.goToFragment(new PostFragment());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I did what you suggested, the method from the activity is called but nothing happened :
{
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.timeline_fragment_layout, fragment);

    transaction.commit();
}
timeline_fragment_layout is the main layout of the fragment with the list view. I`m doing smth wrong but can`t find what. Android development is smth new for me

Comment: Inside your  timeline_fragment_layout resource file you need to declare a FrameLayout with an id of 'container' :) This is where the fragment will be placed. Currently there is no container for the fragment to be placed within.

Comment: Hm, I`m not completely sure what I`m doing wrong but here is the frame Layout: 

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

    </FrameLayout>

I`m opening it : 

 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.detail_container, fragment);

        transaction.commit();

This is called, but the fragment is not showed. I`m sure it is smth very little, but it drives me crazy

Comment: I will try to explain the structure :
 - I have one main activity which is holding the Tab Pager.
 - Have 5 different fragments for the 5 tabs;
 - On first tab I have fragment with list view. The cell for this list view has three buttons, when Clicking on one of the button I need to show detailed fragment, and to keep the tab bar at bottom

Comment: Going to fragments within a ViewPager is very different to navigating through fragments outside of a ViewPager!

When you say you have one main activity which is holding a TabPager - what do you mean? can you post more code?